# Ошибка «NameError: name 'CURL_DIR' is not defined» при установке Python

Tags: python, django

Пробую установить python-lzo-1.08 с gz-архива — получаю ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'CURL_DIR' is not defined
```

Не могу нигде найти виндовс-инсталлер. Везде или gz, или «битые» линки. Может у кого-то завалялся инсталлер? Поделитесь! Или помогите с вышеуказаной ошибкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Искал, искал... нашел! Нашел в наборе пакетов для Python: 
`Base-11.9.17.win32-py2.7`.
Вот залил архив с набором и текстовый со списком пакетов (может кому пригодиьтся):
http://www.fayloobmennik.net/999674